# python neural network loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' vs 'binary_crossentropy' isse

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I've created a neural network for a certain csv, save the neural network values to an h5 file and put it through a checker provided to me. At the moment I have it running by applying to_categorical to the target hit (1 = target hit, 0 = not) column of the data to get whether it hit or not. The other methodology I've tried is to take the target hit column, done 1 - target hit and used

```
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

which should be equivalent of to_categorical but my accuracy, with everything else unchanged reduces by about 20%, what have I done wrong?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

df = pd.read_csv("dataset1.csv")
print(df.head)

Lt = np.array(df['Arm length (m)'][:])
Wt = np.array(df['Ball weight (kg)'][:])
Rt = np.array(df['Ball radius (mm)'][:])
Tt = np.array(df['Air temperature (deg C)'][:])
Et = np.array(df['Spring constant (N per m)'][:])
Dt = np.array(df['Device weight (kg)'][:])
Ot = np.array(df['Target hit'][:])
XtUnscaled = np.column_stack([Lt, Wt, Rt, Tt, Et, Dt])
scaleArray = np.array([np.zeros([6,]), np.ones([6,])])
Xt = (XtUnscaled-scaleArray[0,:])/scaleArray[1,:]
y = np.array(df['Target hit'][:])
Y = to_categorical(y)
# other methodology 
# Y = 1-Ot


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(Xt, yt, epochs=150, batch_size=32)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(Xt, Y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Comment: So your model was performing well with `categorical_crossentropy` and with `binary_crossentropy ` not?

Comment: no, it performed well with Y = 1-Ot, the final layer having 1 node and the compiler loss being binary_crossentropy  and badly with Y=to_categorical(Ot), final layer with 2 nodes and loss = 'categorical_crossentropy"

Answer (score 0):

As your target data has two labels either 0 or 1,This is `binary classification model`.

So use `BinaryCrossentropy` loss for binary (0 or 1) classification and `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` in final layer as `sigmoid` activation function always returns a value between 0 and 1.

`CategoricalCrossentropy` loss function used when there are two or more label classes.